# Determine which controller is sending me Actions in SteamVR

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, steamvr

I'm starting to use the SteamVR action-driven Input system Version: 2.3.2 (sdk 1.4.18). I attached a laser pointer script similar to the Steam version to each controller. Now, when I squeeze the trigger, BOTH scripts receive the squeeze action. Well, of course they do.
So how can I determine if the squeeze is from MY controller to ensure that I only respond to that?

I already looked at the `SteamVR_Input_Sources` parameter. It always reads 'any', so that doesn't help.

Maybe there is an option somewhere to filter which controller messages you wish to receive or a way to determine who invoked the action...?

Comment: You should be able to see it in the unity editor. Give me a sec. I'll get you a better description

Answer (score 1):

You can either subscribe to the action like

```
public void SubscribeToPlayerAction(SteamVR_Action_Boolean action, SteamVR_Action_Boolean.ChangeHandler onAction)
{
    action.AddOnChangeListener(onAction, SteamInputSource); //SteamInputSource can be Left Right or Any
}
```

Or you can poll

```
public bool CheckForPlayerAction(SteamVR_Action_Boolean action, ButtonAction buttonState = ButtonAction.PressDown)
{
    if (buttonState == ButtonAction.PressDown) return action.GetStateDown(SteamInputSource);
    if(buttonState == ButtonAction.IsPressed) return action.GetState(SteamInputSource);

    return action.GetStateUp(SteamInputSource);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anders! I'll go with polling then. I think the new action-driven Input System is not for me (yet?).

Comment: Both examples above use SteamVR 2 actions

Answer (score 0):

If you go to windows and open the SteamVR input live view, you can get this menu

[image]

This menu will show you which controller is receiving an action